# Ubuntu 13.04 to 13.10 upgrade has made drive inaccesable

Tags: upgrade, kernel, filesystem

I recently upgraded to 13.10 from 13.04 , and encountered kernel panic on restarting the system. I have some uncommited code on my drive , so I planed to use live usb to take it out but unfortunately I get this error when I try to open the drive.

[image]

```
Here it the output for dmesg | tail
root@ubuntu:/media# dmesg | tail
[ 1675.866734]         72 03 11 04 00 00 00 0c 00 0a 80 00 00 00 00 00 
[ 1675.866751]         1c a5 98 02 
[ 1675.866759] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]  
[ 1675.866764] Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed
[ 1675.866768] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: 
[ 1675.866771] Read(10): 28 00 1c a5 98 00 00 00 08 00
[ 1675.866786] end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 480614402
[ 1675.866801] ata1: EH complete
[ 1675.866830] JBD2: IO error reading journal superblock
[ 1675.866835] EXT4-fs (sda6): error loading journal
```

and here is the output for fdisk -l

```
root@ubuntu:~# fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 320.1 GB, 320072933376 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 38913 cylinders, total 625142448 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x48000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1              63      353429      176683+  de  Dell Utility
/dev/sda2   *      354304      559103      102400    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3          559104   329183231   164312064    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda4       329185278   625141759   147978241    5  Extended
/dev/sda5       329185280   341938175     6376448   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda6       341940224   625141759   141600768   83  Linux

Disk /dev/sdb: 15.5 GB, 15512174592 bytes
32 heads, 63 sectors/track, 15028 cylinders, total 30297216 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x5bfe1883

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1              63    30296447    15148192+   b  W95 FAT32

Disk /dev/sdc: 4012 MB, 4012900352 bytes
124 heads, 62 sectors/track, 1019 cylinders, total 7837696 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0008de2e

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1   *          62     7834071     3917005    c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)
root@ubuntu:~#
```

Is there anyway I can possibly get my uncommited code out of the drive ?

Comment: To all: I'd rather see this fixed than closed as EOL :)

Comment: BUT Vihaan: I do consider it a bad choice from you to upgrade an end of life release to another end of life release. Please do upgrade to 14.04 after fixing this problem.  And why did you not make a backup if these files are that important? Hmm? ;-)

Comment: I will be updating to 14.04 by today and will definitely make backup while upgrading next time :)

Answer (score 3):

Do a `sudo e2fsck -c /dev/sda6` from a live dvd (review the answers to the questions before confirming it but it should be safe to answer yes to all).

After that check with `sudo e2fsck -c -c -p -v /dev/sda6` if the disk is reporting sane results. Warning: this command will take some time!